# How to perform grep on curl within for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, rhel

I have created an array uisng the command `IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$(command)"`

The array has values:

```
abc001
abc002
abc003
```

I want to loop through the array and run a `curl` command on each element.

> a) If `curl` output has string `Connected` then the `curl` command
>   should `timeout` and the `for loop` should exit out.
>
> b) If the `curl` output is not having string `Connected`  then the
>   `curl` command should `timeout` and `for loop` should move to next
>   element.

I have written the following code.

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
 resp=$(curl -v http://"$element":8888)
 echo resp
done
```

I am getting following output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to abc001 port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* Connected to abc001 port 8888 (#0)
```

Comment: have you tried to see what the return value is of curl if it does connect? Instead of trying to parse for a string, perhaps you can just do `if curl -s '...'; break; fi`

Comment: Also, rather than using command substitution `$(some_command)` followed by a here-string `<<<`, instead use process substitution  as in `< <(some_command)`

Comment: thanks. can you provide updated script?

Comment: Are you just trying to test connectivity instead of looking at content of these websites?

Comment: Yeah I am just trying to test connectivity

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, not tested though should work but.

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
 resp=$(curl -v http://"$element":8888)
 if grep -q "Connected" "$resp"
 then
      echo resp
 fi
done
```

OR

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
 curl http://"$element":8888 -s -f -o /dev/null
 if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
 then
      echo "url $element is working."
 fi
done
```

Comment: the output is stuck at abc001 first element. Do we need to time out in `curl`? I only see following as the output `% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to abc001 port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* Connected to abc001 port 8888 (#0)`

Comment: @meallhour, since I couldn't test it but looks like you may need timeout in curl? Try `--connect-timeout` option once in it and see how it goes then.

Comment: `for element in "${array[@]}"
     do
         $(curl -s --connect-timeout 2 http://"$element":8888)
         if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo Connected to "$element"
         fi
         break;
     done`

Comment: @meallhour, is it still hanging or going through now? could you please do let me know here.

Comment: it is still hanging. really need your help

Comment: also tried `if curl -s 'http://"$element":8888' ; break; fi`  But it is not working and giving syntax error

Comment: @meallhour, sure let me check if I could help here.

Comment: @meallhour, try curl command like `curl your_url -s -f -o /dev/null` then you could check its status like how you shown in your previous command using `$?` lemme know if this helps you?

Comment: getting `syntax error near unexpected token done'`  Can you please update your answer? it will be helpful

Comment: @meallhour, could you please check?

Comment: the script is hanging and I don't any output on the screen. It is a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for element in "${array[@]}"; do
  if curl -m1 -s "http://$element:8888"; then
    echo "'$element' connected" && break
  fi
done
```

Comment: the script is hanging and I dont any output on the screen

Comment: @meallhour something is wrong with your network then.  You can test that mine works if you set `array=( google.nom google.bom google.com)` and then change `:8888` to `:80`.  You'll see that the loop breaks at `google.com` with a 301 Redirect